# Why would Tailwind cause CLS in Next.js on page load?

Tags: css, performance, next.js, tailwind-css, core-web-vitals

I have a very unusual problem with a very specific edge case, however it's impacted our website quite a lot.

I've noticed on slower connections that Tailwind will cause CLS on the `body` element when a page loads in a Next.js application. But... it only happens if a user is scrolling while the page is loading.

To reproduce:

1. Clone this repo and install locally: https://github.com/Dexerto/with-tailwindcss-app
2. Build the project.
3. Start the local server.
4. Open the app in Chrome. Throttle the network connection to Fast 3G.
5. Reload or load the page again.
6. Scroll down while the page is reloading or as soon as it loads.
7. Check CLS (We use the bookmarklet from [this page](https://tamethebots.com/blog-n-bits/web-perf-iv-a-new-hope))

With scrolling causes CLS:

[Website screenshot with CLS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCKv4.png)

Without scrolling or faster connection there is no CLS:

[Website screenshot without CLS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ta8fm.png)

This is the layout shift object:

```
{
    "name": "",
    "entryType": "layout-shift",
    "startTime": 1347.2999999999884,
    "duration": 0,
    "value": 1,
    "hadRecentInput": false,
    "lastInputTime": 0,
    "sources": [
        {
            "previousRect": {
                "x": 8,
                "y": 0,
                "width": 1424,
                "height": 764,
                "top": 0,
                "right": 1432,
                "bottom": 764,
                "left": 8
            },
            "currentRect": {
                "x": 0,
                "y": 0,
                "width": 1440,
                "height": 764,
                "top": 0,
                "right": 1440,
                "bottom": 764,
                "left": 0
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Just to note, I can't visually see and shift. The page loads with no movement of any element. When I remove the base and utilities styles I don't get any CLS, so my assumption is that it's Tailwind related.

I understand this is a small edge case, but our users seem to be inpatient and scroll down while the page is loading!

Does anybody know why this could happen?

My initial thought was that it was the Tailwind preflight styles causing an issue, so I took out the `base` styles imported from Tailwind, manually added each style and then went through each one to see if it rectified the issue. Eventually this actually did, but when I added the `utilities` styles back in the problem returned.

I expect the page to load with no CLS. However it is loading with a maximum CLS score of 1.